# Look for a specific keyword in a range of cells in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Is there an MS Excel formula that can look for some specific keywords within a range of cells given? For example, I'm looking for the words "Computer" and "Hardware" from cells D5 to G5, if one of those words exists within that range, it will return a value to cell C5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following formula in `C5` cell.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(IFERROR(MATCH("*Computer*",D5:G5,0),MATCH("*Hardware*",D5:G5,0))),"Keyword Found","")
```

Comment: Can I also nest this formula? I tried this code but it shows an error:

=IF(ISNUMBER(IFERROR(MATCH("*Har*",D517:H517,0),MATCH("*Netw*",D517:H517,0))),6, ISNUMBER(IFERROR(MATCH("*Soft*", D517:H517,0))),7,"")

I'm trying to find a different a different word but it will return the value 7 if found.

Comment: You can, may you need to use wild card `*` if the word you searching is not only word on those cells.